# SVN - undo an integrate of trunk to branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn

I have got a branch, let's say A, off trunk and have accidentally done the following:

- Create Branch A off trunk
- Make changes to Branch A
- I want to merge trunk to branch A to get latest from trunk BUT instead of a merge, I do a 'reintegrate' - reintegrate trunk to my branch

I have read that after reintegration, we run into cyclic merge issues; however, all articles reintegrate branch to trunk and I've done it the other way around.

I'm using SVN version 1.7.
I cannot do a 'record-only' commit to trunk

Is there a way I can get my branch to accept trunk changes again? Can I just revert the 'reintegrate merge' from trunk to my branch revision of my branch?

I want to ensure that trunk is stable and can accept my branch A final changes. In addition, my branch A is stable and can accept trunk changes as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have merged changes from trunk to branch and want the branch back in previous state in which it was before merge you can do the following :

1. Use SVN log command and check the revision no before the merge happened .
2. Do reverse merging for getting the previous state 
   " svn merge -r HEAD:stable-revision-branch .  "
3. Do svn commit .

Please refer the link for more clarification [SVN reverse merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930725/svn-reverse-merge)

Regards

Jyotsna

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This is very interesting and I hope I had seen this message earlier. As of now, I've created a new feature branch from my current feature branch. The new feature branch has been taken out from the version previous to the merge... This solution is simpler and I'll keep this in mind