# Unbork svn working copy

Tags: svn

after attempting to work through one of those "item deleted on update" conflict, I'm now at the point where the latest revision of the trunk has the files, but my working copy, with svn info showing it to be at the same revision, does not show the files.  svn status shows a D next to the files in question, but the server browser still shows the files as officially part of the repo.

svn status does not show a conflict, svn revert doesn't work, deleting the folder and then doing svn update doesn't bring the files back.  since the server browser seems to show the files i'm sure the problem is with my working copy, but I can't blow the whole working copy away just to get these files back in.  I could use some pointers here.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> svn status shows a D next to the files in question, but the server browser still shows the files as officially part of the repo.

This indicates that you've deleted the item in your working copy, but haven't committed the change.

> svn revert doesn't work

`svn revert` may not, if you don't properly tell it what to revert. You may need to use `svn revert --recursive` to revert all changes in that directory and lower.

Worst case, commit your changes, then perform a [reverse merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1930811/1324345) to undo that revision. You can't break the repository from the client; you can always get back to a known good state.

Comment: specifically, I wanted to keep the files after all, and revert --recursive took care of the unwanted delete on the folder of files.  Thanks.