# deleting revisions from repository in subclipse (possibly need to merge trunk with branch)

Tags: svn, subclipse

I need to delete 3 revisions from the trunk (completely remove it). So far I can revert changes but I don't know how to completely remove the not working revisions. Can somebody please help?

Somebody told me to merge from branch to trunk but the last branch revision is 296 and the current working trunk revision is 396, the current trunk revision is 399. -
So first I need version 396 in branch: Merging from trunk to branch does nothing: the branch remains on version 296.

I didn't find an appropriate solution/description on the internet, so that i know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Greetings Zehke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove a revision in the literal sense.  Once a revision is created it exists forever.  The only way to remove something from the repository is to dump it to a dump file, then filter out the revisions you want to remove from the dump file, then load that new dump file to a new repository.

If you just want to undo those changes in the current HEAD, then the way to do that is with a [reverse merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930725/svn-reverse-merge).  I personally prefer doing it via the command line using the negative syntax.  Something like:

```
svn merge -c-395 ^/trunk
```

Which would undo the change made in r395.